# Human chat on whatsapp chatbots

Tags: chatbot, whatsapp

I have official WhatsApp API number with a chatbot.
When costumers sends messages, how can I chat with them (human chat)?
Only on my providor's dashboard?
or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your BSP provides another chat mechanism you will be limited to the dashboard they provide, I would suggest reaching out to them with this inquiry.

Behind the scenes they build on top of a WhatsApp provided API, so you are restricted to the tools which they've build on-top of this API.